# How to create datatemplate in code behind with listview gridview for a treeview

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

Hi Please help me to realize the fallowing datatemplate in code behind

```
<TreeView Name="OrderTree" DataContext="{Binding ordersTree}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
              ...
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ordVM:OrderedDataCollectionVM}">
            <ListView Name="orderedListView" Margin="0,5,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Number}" Width="20" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static lang:ViewTextResource.product_name}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Product.Name}" Width="150" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding GridHeaders.[0]}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewComboBox1}" Width="120"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding GridHeaders.[1]}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewComboBox2}" Width="120"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

I want to create a DataTemplate in code behind for my TreeView with a ListView which has a GridView which columns count depends on my data.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6b3ff2e5-7084-43a7-a3a2-a7c787b61339/). Looks like it's what you want.

The interesting part:

```
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();  

template.VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Path));  

template.VisualTree.SetBinding(Path.StrokeProperty, new Binding("Stroke"));  
template.VisualTree.SetBinding(Path.StrokeThicknessProperty, new Binding("StrokeThickness"));  
template.VisualTree.SetBinding(Path.FillProperty, new Binding("Interior"));  
template.VisualTree.SetBinding(Path.DataProperty, new Binding("Geometry"));
```

Just edit it to suit your needs.